# Загрузка CSV файлa в БД

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.x

Не получается загрузка в БД.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv

user = "test"
pw = "rest"
dsn = "localhost"
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user,pw,dsn)
print("Database version:", con.version)
if con:
    print('connect')
else:
    print('not connect')
cur = con.cursor()
with open('names.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
# print(spamreader)
next(spamreader, None)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(11.09.2017 00:00:00,test1,test2,test3,922-100,3600)")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Ошибка:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: после 2017 где запятая?

Comment: @PavelGridin поставил, все же такая же ошибка

Comment: стоп, а после mytable, же должен быть список полей и только потом VALUES

Comment: @PavelGridin такая нотация допустима, если количество и тип `VALUES` соответствует колонкам таблицы.

Comment: может формат даты/времени не понимает, обычно их так впрямую не указывают, но я вашей библиотеки не знаю, я в qt бд занимаюсь, попробуйте дату в формате MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: В SQL все строковые литералы должны быть обрамлены одиночными кавычками. Но лучше, конечно, использовать `bind variables` и передавать все значения как параметры, чтобы избежать `SQL Injections` и по скорости это будет работать гораздо быстрее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) чтобы загрузить данные из CSV файла в таблицу Oracle:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection_string = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:password@tnsname')

# create SQL Alchemy connection object
engine = create_engine(connection_string)

df = pd.read_csv('names.csv', sep=';', quotechar='|')

df.to_sql("mytable", engine, if_exists="append")
```

PS можно попробовать напрямую воспользоваться cx_Oracle connection - `conn` вместо `engine`, но в документации просят использовать `connection` или `engine` объект из `SQL Alchemy`:

```
df.to_sql("mytable", con, if_exists="append")
```